# preg_match_all not working php

Tags: php, escaping, preg-match-all

Using `preg_match_all`, I able to use it with double quotes by escaping them with a `\` but I cant figure the below out.  I know you have to escape double quotes.. but still won't work with the HTML code below

in the `$html` I have

```
 $html = 'ofReports_ceptframe")[0].src = "https://www.example.com";';
```

I want to extract the URL from src =

I tried

```
 preg_match_all("/[0].src \= \"(.*?)\"/is", $html, $matches);
 foreach($matches[1] as $url); 
 echo $url;
```

but does not return anything

Answer (score 2):

`[` and `]` have special meaning, you have to escape them:

```
preg_match_all("/\[0\]\.src = \"(.*?)\"/is", $html, $matches);
```

To print results one by one:

```
foreach ($matches[1] as $url) {
    echo "$url\n";
}
```

Comment: I would also escape the `.` you have there (before the `src`).

Comment: @Dekel:Thank you.

Comment: @newuser0250: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: thanks i tried to vote up it wouldnt let me, where is the accept button?

Comment: also how can i make preg match or preg match print for each result, instead of entire result?

Comment: @newuser0250:I didn't talk about upvote(you will have soon this privilege (see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). I mean accepting answer,( from help center: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.).